# Can I connect multiple OpenVPN client connections to different VPNs, each accessed through socks proxy?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, socks, socks5-proxy

I have a piece of software, I'll call it "FooSoft" here, which needs to connect to multiple devices on networks protected by a variety of third party VPNs. Each VPN is independent and I have no control over the setup of these VPNs or the network behind them. FooSoft supports connecting to socks5 proxies to transfer data.

If I use [OpenConnect with ocproxy](https://github.com/cernekee/ocproxy) it seems that I can have a socks5 proxy that FooSoft connects to, and that only this traffic is directed through the particular VPN connection, allowing me to have multiple VPN connections, each behind a socks5 proxy and not interfering with one another (right?).

However, it's not clear that the same is possible for OpenVPN? The [documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/) mentions an option `socks-proxy`, but I'm not sure if this expects there to be an existing socks proxy running already or if it creates one and routes the traffic through it.

Therefore, my question is, how can connect to one or more simultaneous OpenVPN VPN connections each through a corresponding socks proxy?